# First Order Linear Differential Equation with $ P(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A first order linear differential equation can be written as:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + P(x) y = Q(x)$$

If $P(x)$ here is equal to zero, will the differential equation still be linear?

Comment: What sort of conditions do you demand $P(x)$ to satisfy in this context? What is your reference?

Comment: From what I read, P and Q can be constants and I'm defining P to be a constant = 0

Comment: Then it seems you've already answered your own question!

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: YES

---

**Long answer**:

consider the operator 
$$L y = \frac{dy}{dx} + P y$$ 
and let $y_1$ and $y_2$ two differentiable functions. Then:

$$\begin{align}
 L[\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2 ] = & \, \frac{d}{dx}(\alpha y_1+ \beta y_2 ) + P(\alpha y_1+ \beta y_2)   \\
= & \,\alpha y'_1 + \beta y'_2  + P y_1 + P y_2 \\
= & \, \alpha Ly_1 + \beta Ly_2
\end{align}$$
where we have taken advantage of the linear character of the operator $d/dx$. Hence, since $P$ is a function which only depends on $x$, we can conclude that $L$ is a linear operator. Thus the ODE $Ly = Q$ is linear as well.

Discussing the conditions on $P$ and $Q$ for the solution to exist is another thing.

Cheers!